# How to call for Container from Routes?

Tags: php

I have created a Router based on [Fast-rout](https://github.com/middlewares/fast-route) and Container based on [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/).

It is a fragment of my Router's code:

```
$container = require __DIR__ . '/../config/Container.php';
$logger = $container->get(myLogger::class); 

$routes = simpleDispatcher(function (RouteCollector $r) {
    $routes = include('config/Routes.php');

    foreach ($routes as $key => $route) {
       $r->addRoute($route[0], $route[1], $route[2] );  
    }

});

$logger->warning('123'); 


$middlewareQueue[] = new FastRoute($routes);
$middlewareQueue[] = new RequestHandler($container);

$requestHandler = new Relay($middlewareQueue);
$requestHandler->handle(ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals());
```

You could see that I call for Logger from the Container instance. However, I have no idea how to pass container into Classes which are being initialized through the Router.

For example,   if I request '`/3`' in a browser there is TestMe class is running (`route ['GET', '/3', TestMe::class]` ). And I am able to render page or emit response from it. But I can't to use $container from it although looks like I add it into middleware:     `$middlewareQueue[] = new RequestHandler($container);`

Comment: When you dispatch the router, you should get the matched route back, including it's callback handler. Then you can resolve that in your container. No need to pass it to the router. That's at least how the original [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute#usage) library does it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you for your support! I have learned it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that `new RequestHandler($container);` is also from Relay, which uses the container for resolving requests as a middleware but does not pass it around otherwise because it would be a service locator.

**1. Quick clarification about "using" the container in classes.**

Rather than trying to pass the container to the classes, use the container to inject each class with its dependencies, ideally with type-hinting.

For instance, if you want to use that logger in a class, it should not be through `$container->get(myLogger::class)`. Instead, something like this:

```
use myLogger;

class MyClass

public $logger;

public function __construct(myLogger $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

You can then use `$this->logger` in the methods.

**2. container working with the router:**

What you want to achieve should be the *last* middleware before the dispatch.

- It should have the container in its constructor.
- It should receive the matched route and based on its definitions it should initialize the matched class (or function).
- During this initialization, it can inject that class with its dependencies.

There are two good examples I suggest you consider. First the [Harmony library](https://github.com/woohoolabs/harmony/blob/master/src/Middleware/DispatcherMiddleware.php) and you see how it uses the container as described above. Second, since you're using custom versions of FastRoute and PHP-DI, look at the index file of the [PHP-DI demo](https://github.com/PHP-DI/demo/blob/master/web/index.php). Although it's not a psr-15 use, it shows how to use PHP-DI to call matched routes of FastRoute.

Good luck to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for a such good answer with details. You have helped me a lot. Wish you good luck in all of your projects and plans!